# RabbitMQ connection automatic recovery

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm a little confused about the automatic recovery of the connections in RabbitMQ java client.

Consider the following code

```
ConnectionFactory factory;
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel chan_obj = conn.createChannel();
```

As per RabbitMQ documentation, if connection drops, then automatically recovery will re-create the connection, re-create the channel etc.
I'm really confused about what to do with the 'chan_obj' while RabbitMQ automatically recovers.
I'm curious if the 'channel' created from the connection after the recovery will be usable with the object 'chan_obj'
Another question is during the recovery process, will I get any notification that channel has closed and hopefully followed by another notification like 'channel can be used again'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cite the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.5/index.html?com/rabbitmq/client/Connection.html)

```
Create a new channel, using an internally allocated
channel number. If automatic connection recovery is
enabled, the channel returned by this method will
be Recoverable.
```

See also [AutorecoveringConnection](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.5/index.html?com/rabbitmq/client/impl/recovery/AutorecoveringConnection.html) and [AutorecoveringChannel](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.5/index.html?com/rabbitmq/client/impl/recovery/AutorecoveringChannel.html).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm curious if the 'channel' created from the connection after the
> recovery will be usable with the object 'chan_obj'

Yes, it will be usable, **but until the recovery is completed** (normally, it takes a few seconds to switch to a live RabbitMQ node), an operation on chan_obj can cause an exception with a text similar to this:
`The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=320, text='CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'', classId=0, methodId=0`.

> Another question is during the recovery process, will I get any
> notification that channel has closed and hopefully followed by another
> notification like 'channel can be used again'.

Not sure if it's implemented in the Java RabbitMQ client library, because the standard approach for handling connection/channel failures is to implement a retry logic (e.g. try performing the same operation on a channel several times with some delay).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @civtorm1710's answer:

- If you are using `spring-rabbit`, don't care about the retry or auto-recovery things, spring will handle the connection lost issue very well;
- By default RabbitMQ client will retry at a interval of 5s, so you can just retry you operation at a interval of 5.5s or so. And the delay is customizable, see `ConnectionFactory.setRecoveryDelayHandler` and `ConnectionFactory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval`;
- If you want to be notified when connection recovery is completed, you can add a listener to the connection, see `AutorecoveringConnection.addRecoveryListener`;